# How do I identify bivariate outliers along the regression line?

Tags: r, regression, standard-deviation

I need to detect the outliers of this scatterplot, made with plotly. In particular, I want to select all points that fall outside a certain threshold. Apologies for the screenshot, it's just to give an idea.
[image]

I have a dataframe df with Vol1, Vol2 and sd (that is the standard deviation calculated for Vol and Vol2, for each row). I calculated the residuals of the linear regression, then I considered the standard deviation as the mean of sd.
Here it is part of the code, in R:

```
lm_model <- lm(Vol2 ~ Vol1, data = df[,c(2:3)])
residuals <- lm_model$residuals

sd_residuals <- sd(residuals)
outliers <- df[which(abs(residuals) > 3 * sd_residuals), ]

plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Vol1, y = ~Vol2, text = ~rownames, mode = "markers", type = "scatter") 
%>% add_trace(data = outliers, x = ~Vol1, y = ~Vol2, mode = "markers", marker = list(color = 
"red"))
```

The point is that I'm not considering the standard deviation that I have in my dataframe (and somehow I should, according to the data). I tried putting  `sd_residuals <- mean(df$sd)` and the result is slightly better, but still it's not what I want.

Can you please explain me how to retrieve the outliers?

Comment: (1) There is no agreed definition of outliers; any threshold will have to be chosen by the user, depending on the aim of analysis, meaning of the data etc. (2) A regression will not treat Vol1 and Vol2 symmetrically. Is this what you want? (3) Standard least squares regression will itself be affected by outliers, and outlier identification is better based on robust regression such as function ````lmrob```` in package ````robustbase```` (if you want regression at all that is).

Comment: I am not sure what use the SD of each row is. Maybe I am missing something. 

But, with outliers, you need to define your threshold.  The diagnostic plots from an lm in R can help. Try plot(lm_model) .

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I need to find a solution that can be used with different samples, so the threshold has to be calculated using the data that I have (also I cannot install other packages so unfortunately robustbase is not avaiable). I though that playing around with the sd might be the solution. To give you some context, this selection was initially provided by the user, that used to select manually the outliers according to how the plot was. I would like to find a solution to standardize this process, but it's fine even if it's just a "general solution".

Comment: You might look at orthogonal regression, since you seem to be interested in the total deviation from the line rather than in a dependent variable only. If SD is a measure of the statistical precision of the values of vol1 and vol2, then you should probably weight the errors accordingly.